# how to manage api response with view model

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have an API which sends error status flag, error message and object of user. Currently I am using the API response class to get these responses.

```
public class UsersResponse
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I receive the response in the instance of the above mentioned class and later display the result on the view. I get the response in the view's code behind file.

I was wondering if this is the right way to do it? If view models are used, will it be tackled by view model? If yes, then how will it be done.

I am thinking of getting into the habit of using view models rather than fully relying on the views code behind file.

The best way to tackle such a situation will be of great help and highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose a INPC property like `IsBusy` in the ViewModel, turn it on before accessing your long running process (better make it async), then turn it off.

You shouldn't be loading data in the code-behind, in MVVM the code-behind should be minimized and restricted to view-specific only code (e.g. if you have several platforms). Think of code behind like JS for HTML, even less than that.
It's the ViewModel that should take care of loading the data and manipulating it. ViewModel = The model of the view.

Comment: Ok, but my question is that, is the class that i am using the proper may to get response from the api or the response should somehow map directly to the viewmodel? Is the UserResponse class really required or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The idea is that you're loading your response in the viewmodel, and bind to it from your view. It all depends in the API and the toolset available for it.